# Use Python to scape html with anti-scrape protection

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping so bear with me please.

Trying to scrape a site with Python. Specifically, the information within section `<h2>Parties</h2>`.

The site needs log in and the computer logs in automatically. When I view the html in firefox, i was able to see what is within `"<h2>Parties</h2>"` section. However, when i try accessing it from Python and copy/save the html to a notepad, it shows as below:

```
<h2>Parties</h2>
<div class="trialText">To view the parties, register now.</div>
<input type="hidden" id="hdnTeaserIndicator" value="true" />
```

Turns out this part of information on the webpage needs login to be viewed. Since the company computer logs in automatically, I have access to the info through Firefox, but not through Python. This also means - I don't know the User ID/PW. Is there a way to automatically log in when scraping in Python without entering the user credentials? (I have this "idea" that maybe the browser in Python could connect with IE/Firefox, but I am not sure how it actually works, or if it is possible)

Thanks

Comment: Take the hint. **Don't scrape sites that don't want to be scraped**

Comment: If you're posting content from scraped sites on your site without permission, you will be open to being sued. It will also be trivial for the scraping victim to block your bot, so all your work would be for nothing.

Comment: I agree with the warnings, but maybe it is a site where you are allowed to read the content. Probably you just did not quite understand how "logging in" and "being logged in" works. Hint: Cookie and/or https.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments/concerns. Please see updated post. flaschenpost - i think you're right, i will look into these.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the mechanize library to log in, and scrape the resulting web page with something like beautiful soup.